# Python: setting image pixel value not working

Tags: python

I wrote a method that makes certain pixel values of an image white. 
Within that method, I called a method I wrote called "meanfilter"
When I call that method, the pixel values are not assigned to that image. However when I delete that call, the code works just fine. I don't know why that is the case. 
here is my code:

```
def getColorArrayFromFiltered(self,image):
    image=Image.open(image).convert("RGBA")

    image=image.resize((100,100))
    #tempImage is another image from somewhere else
    imagepix1 = self.tempImage.load()
    imagepix2 = image.load()
    count = 0

    image= self.meanFilter(image,3)
    for x in range(100):
        for y in range(100):
            if self.isWhite(imagepix1[x,y]):
                count+=1
                imagepix2[x,y]=(255,255,255)

    print count         
    image.save("dddd.png")
```

in the code above, count was around 5000 so I expected at least half the image to be white, but it isn't.

Here is my mean filter method:

```
def meanFilter(self,image,fraction):
        w,h = image.size
        image=image.convert("RGBA")
        sections=w/fraction
        area = fraction * fraction
        imagepix=image.load()
        i=-1
        j=-1
        count = 0
        countActual = 0
        pixArray =[]
        while i<sections-1:
            j=-1
            i+=1
            while j<sections-1:
                j+=1
                for a in range(i*fraction,(1+i)*(fraction)):
                    for b in range(j*fraction,(1+j)*(fraction)):
                        rgb=imagepix[a,b]

                        if pixArray:
                            if abs(rgb[0]-255)>5 and abs(rgb[1]-255)>5 and abs(rgb[2]-255)>5 and not self.isBlack(rgb):
                                pixArray=map(lambda x,y: x+y,rgb,pixArray);
                                countActual +=1
                        else:
                            pixArray=rgb
                            countActual+=1

                if countActual!=0:      
                        mean = (int(pixArray[0]/countActual),int(pixArray[1]/countActual),int(pixArray[2]/countActual),int(pixArray[3]/countActual))                
                        for a in range(i*fraction,(1+i)*(fraction)):
                            for b in range(j*fraction,(1+j)*(fraction)):
                                    imagepix[a,b]=mean

                countActual = 0
                pixArray=[]
        return image
```

Comment: maybe because of load? try to put `imagepix2 = image.load()`  **after** the filter

Comment: @valentin you were right! thank you so much!